# tkinter pack vs grid methods: Scrollbar appearances

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Below shows the right bottom corner of a Tk window that consists of a frame that consists of a Canvas and horizontal and vertical scrollbars. This was achieved using the Grid method.

[image: Right bottom corner by the Grid method.]

I am not able to replicate the same look using the Pack method. Below is what I get and the sample code giving such a look.

[image: Right bottom corner by the Pack method.]

How do I replicate the look by the grid method using the pack method?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame( root )
frame.pack()

ysb = ttk.Scrollbar( frame, orient='vertical' )
xsb = ttk.Scrollbar( frame, orient='horizontal' )

canvas = tk.Canvas( frame, width=1000, height=700, background='green')
canvas.create_rectangle( 100, 100, 900, 600, fill='yellow' )
canvas.configure( scrollregion=canvas.bbox(tk.ALL),
                  xscrollcommand=xsb.set,
                  yscrollcommand=ysb.set )

xsb.config( command=canvas.xview )
ysb.config( command=canvas.yview )

ysb.pack( side='right', fill='y', expand=1)
xsb.pack( side='bottom', fill='x', expand=1 )
canvas.pack( side='left', fill='both', expand=1 )

#ysb.grid( row=0, column=1, sticky='ns' )
#xsb.grid( row=1, column=0, sticky='ew' )
#canvas.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )
```

Comment: If you can do what you want with `grid`, why do you need a solution using `pack`?

Comment: @BryanOakley The actual code had widgets positioned by the Pack method. The use of the grid method in my sample to show the desired outcome, which I was not getting with `pack`. @acw1668 solution has helped me better understand the pack method.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your actual code is using `pack`. You can create a frame and place it with `pack`,and the use `grid` to place the scrollbars and canvas in the frame.

Comment: Sorry for not clearly explaining. The actual code had a canvas that was already packed. I can't combine the `grid` method with the existing `pack` method.

Comment: @SunBear Actually your code has put the canvas and the two scrollbars inside a frame (`frame`), therefore you can use `grid()` inside that frame to layout the canvas and the two scrollbars if there is no other widget in the same frame.  Then you can use `pack()` on the frame with other widgets that are children of `root`.  You cannot mix `pack()` and `grid()` in __same__ container.  `frame` is a container and `root` is another.  So using `grid()` inside `frame` will not conflict to using `pack()` inside `root`.

Comment: @acw1668 Within the frame, there is actually another widget that seems to be related to the canvas widget, which I did not include in this example. I had earlier done what you had described earlier. However, it caused a conflict when `grid` was used on the canvas. `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!xxxxx which already has slaves managed by pack`. Hence, I resorted to using the `pack` method within the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pady` to achieve it:

```
h = xsb.winfo_reqheight() # get the height of horizontal scrollbar
ysb.pack(side='right', fill='y', pady=(0,h)) # set bottom pady
```